# Query to join multiple columns from one table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I am trying to compare values of 3 different pieces of data from the same table. The table I am getting information contains the columns DescriptionID, DateTime, and Data. I want to compare the values of the data for different DescriptionIDs when the dateTime is + or - one minute of eachother. I used a join to do it with two Description IDs as follows:

```
Select a.DescriptionID, b.DescriptionID, a.Data, a.DateTime as 'DataA',b.Data as 'DataB' 
From(
SELECT TOP 1000 [DescriptionID]
      ,[MachineID]
      ,[DateTime]
      ,[Data]
  FROM [ACQDATA].[dbo].[AlarmData] where DescriptionID =1014 order by dateTime desc )
  as a
  inner join (
  SELECT TOP 1000 [DescriptionID]
      ,[MachineID]
      ,[DateTime]
      ,[Data]
  FROM [ACQDATA].[dbo].[AlarmData] where DescriptionID=1914  order by dateTime desc 
  ) as b 
  on a.DateTime BETWEEN (DATEADD(minute, -1,  b.Datetime))  AND (DATEADD(minute, 1,  b.Datetime))

  where b.Data='True'or b.Data = 'False'
```

I thought that I might be able to just do another join where I joined it with what I made above, and then the Select query again. However, that did not seem to work.

I am pretty new to SQL so if I am going in the totally wrong direction let me know.

Changed to:

```
WITH myData1014 AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1000 [DescriptionID]
      ,[MachineID]
      ,[DateTime]
      ,[Data]
    FROM [ACQDATA].[dbo].[AlarmData] where DescriptionID =1014 order by dateTime desc 
)
,myData1914 AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1000 [DescriptionID]
      ,[MachineID]
      ,[DateTime]
      ,[Data]
      ,DATEADD(MINUTE,1,[DateTime]) AS DatPlus1
      ,DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,[DateTime]) AS DatMinus1
    FROM [ACQDATA].[dbo].[AlarmData] where DescriptionID =1914 order by dateTime desc 
)
,myData1005 AS
(
 SELECT TOP 1000 [DescriptionID]
      ,[MachineID]
      ,[DateTime]
      ,[Data]
      ,DATEADD(MINUTE,1,[DateTime]) AS DatPlus1
      ,DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,[DateTime]) AS DatMinus1
    FROM [ACQDATA].[dbo].[AlarmData] where DescriptionID =1005 order by dateTime desc 
)
SELECT *
FROM myData1014
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT Data
    FROM myData1914
    WHERE myData1014.[DateTime] BETWEEN myData1914.DatMinus1 AND myData1914.DatPlus1 
) AS Details1914
Where Details1914.Data='True' or Details1914.Data='False'
```

Now how do I use myData 1005?

Comment: I don't seem to understand what you are exactly looking for. Why are you comparing two different DescriptionID in the same table? How do you otherwise join back to the same table if the DescriptionID is different on both tables?

Comment: Is there a reason for "TOP 1000"? How many rows may be there? Normally one should use the ORDER BY in the outermost query only...

Comment: @NepaliRookie I am trying to compare values of the Data column for the when they are the same date and time. Each description ID relates to an alarm from a machine where the values are true and false. I wanted to see if I could find a correlation between them. ie when DescIDA = false, and DescIDB=true=> DescIDC = true

Comment: @Shnugo Im a SQL noob :P. I dont make efficient decisions with my choices, I kind of try just to make it work

Comment: @ColeGordon, Never mind :-) For the moment it would be a very wise and efficient choice to answer the questions :-))

Comment: @ColeGordon, now you just add one more OUTER APPLY. As I do not know what your result set should look like, it is really difficult to help. If my answer was usefull, please vote up and/or tick it as accepted, thx

Comment: Well where do i put the outer apply, and does there need to be anything before/ after it. Then you will earn your well deserved upvote/ accepted:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reserved words as column names ("DateTime") is not a good idea...

But - anyway - this could help:

I use CTEs to handle your subsets as if they were selfstanding tables.
It is completely untested and - actually - I cannot quite image what you really want... :-)

```
WITH myData1014 AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1000 [DescriptionID]
      ,[MachineID]
      ,[DateTime]
      ,[Data]
    FROM [ACQDATA].[dbo].[AlarmData] where DescriptionID =1014 order by dateTime desc 
)
,myData1914 AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1000 [DescriptionID]
      ,[MachineID]
      ,[DateTime]
      ,[Data]
      ,DATEADD(MINUTE,1,[DateTime]) AS DatPlus1
      ,DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,[DateTime]) AS DatMinus1
    FROM [ACQDATA].[dbo].[AlarmData] where DescriptionID =1914 order by dateTime desc 
)
,myData1005 AS
(
 SELECT TOP 1000 [DescriptionID]
      ,[MachineID]
      ,[DateTime]
      ,[Data]
      ,DATEADD(MINUTE,1,[DateTime]) AS DatPlus1
      ,DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,[DateTime]) AS DatMinus1
    FROM [ACQDATA].[dbo].[AlarmData] where DescriptionID =1005 order by dateTime desc 
)
SELECT *
FROM myData1014
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT Data
    FROM myData1914
    WHERE myData1014.[DateTime] BETWEEN myData1914.DatMinus1 AND myData1914.DatPlus1 
) AS Details1914
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT Data
    FROM myData1005
    WHERE myData1014.[DateTime] BETWEEN myData1005.DatMinus1 AND myData1005.DatPlus1 
) AS Details1005
Where Details1914.Data='True' or Details1914.Data='False' --True OR False will always be true ???
```

Comment: Hey your suggestion got me to have a similar looking table to what I already produced. I tried adding the other column to it, but I don't know the logic of with or apply. I updated to where I am at in the description. And FYI I didnt make the DateTime column, so dont blame me

Comment: thx, just extended my example, but I'm glad you got it on your own!